# Implementing switch on hover CSS

Tags: html, css

i will need some help if possible. I want to implement into these 2 cards the image switch on hover.

I want to make it like this  (code also provided in the link)

https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=faq&file=changing-image-on-hover-with-css

Thank you guys, highly appreciated!

Comment: You Just put two card design. You have to use javascript to change the whole card with another card. And there is no :hover effect on your code.

Comment: The example you provided does this already. See line 13 (`.card:hover`)

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend using `background-image` because that sets a background for the element/page as a whole -- I used the `content` property instead, but you can easily switch it out. As well, the two images you gave are hosted on a website with no SSL certificate, so I uploaded the same image onto imgur.

The code is below. Make sure to set width and height dimensions in the CSS to fit your needs (perhaps you want the images to be smaller, for example).

```css
.fan {
  content:url("https://i.imgur.com/XJDGjDI.jpg");
}

.fan:hover {
  content:url("https://i.imgur.com/FTmXIIf.jpg");
}
```

```html
<body>
  <img class="fan"></div>
</body>
```

---

If you'd like, you can also do this same thing with a little JavaScript, which you could put in a `<script>` tag in the HTML, or in its own document. See:

```js
function back() {
  document.getElementById('fan').src = "https://i.imgur.com/FTmXIIf.jpg"
}

function front() {
  document.getElementById('fan').src = "https://i.imgur.com/XJDGjDI.jpg"
}
```

```html
<img onmouseover="back()" onmouseout="front()" src="https://i.imgur.com/XJDGjDI.jpg" id="fan">
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the image tag in your html and add a DIV tag with an identifier `id="someid"` you can use in CSS to set `properties` to, then add css to set the `background` to an image. Then set a css property for the `hover` state `:hover` and change the background `url()` to the desired image you wish to display on hover.

```css
#rebel2 {
   background: url('http://motopara.com/img/Rebel2_SS_Logo.jpg') no-repeat;
   width: 685px;
   height: 865px;
}

#rebel2:hover {
background: url('https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcTm_KZm-pk_XMbnu2-5L5pVDoxNG8Fax1k4PWE7F1Tie8IMQdpe&usqp=CAU') no-repeat;
    width: 685px;
   height: 865px;
}
```

```html
<div style="overflow:auto;"> 
<div class="column">
<!-- CARD BEGIN-->
<div class="card">
<div class="column-margin">
<font color="#000000"><p>REBEL 2 RS</p></font>
  <hr/>
    <div id="rebel2"></div><!-- Removed the image tag and added a div that the css background can have a url added to it-->
  <hr/>
  <div class="center">
    <div class="skewed-heading-bg">
      <div class="skewed-heading-content"> <a href="rebel2.php" style="color:#FFFFFF;"><span style="font-size:12px;">DETAILS</span><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right" style="font-size: 16px; padding-left: 5px;"></i></a> </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div></div>
<!-- CARD END-->
<div class="column">
<!-- CARD BEGIN-->
<div class="card">
<div class="column-margin">
  <font color="#000000"><p>ALPHA</p></font>
  <hr/>
  <img src="http://motopara.com/img/sim_n_rob.jpg" alt="EVO Alpha PPG Frame" style="width:95%">
  <hr/> 
  <div class="center">
    <div class="skewed-heading-bg">
      <div class="skewed-heading-content"><a href="alpha.php" style="color:#FFFFFF;"> <span style="font-size:12px;">DETAILS</span><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right" style="font-size: 16px; padding-left: 5px;"></i> </a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```